# linker error while linking with C++ mongoclient driver 2.4

Tags: c++, mongo-cxx-driver

I am getting one linker error while trying to link the application against mongodb C++ driver. I am not sure what is going wrong.

```
(.rodata._ZTVN5mongo16ConnectExceptionE[_ZTVN5mongo16ConnectExceptionE]+0x40): undefined reference to `mongo::DBException::toString() const'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using such a terribly outdated version of the C++ driver? You will have much better luck using the latest version of the legacy C++ driver:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/releases/tag/legacy-1.1.0

Even better, use the new C++11 driver:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/releases/tag/r3.0.0